# Easy way to rotate an image as ByteArray in another byteArray without drawing it

Tags: java, image

I'm looking for an easy way to rotate a byteArray in a specific angle (not jut 90°, 180°, 270°) but all solutions I can find finish with g2D.drawImage(). I don't want to draw the image but only modify a byteArray.

This might be really simple and maybe it only miss me the correct keywords to find relevant answers.

Any Help appreciated, Class name, Tutorials, code extracts...
thanks :-)

Comment: Perhaps try [creating a rotated bitmap, and then convert back to byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16951001/4342563).

Comment: Sorry for the late of my answer, it worked, thanks a lot :)